# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:while trying to lookup jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I am migrating one project(already devloped by someone) from one Weblogic instance to another. While deploying it is giving me error "*javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:while trying to lookup jdbc.##/##DS. didn't find subcontext 'jdbc' "Resolved"*".

I have created JNDI name and configured same in the application.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have created the JNDI name and configured it how?

Answer (score 0):

Commonly this error occurs if you do not set a Target Server or don't target the correct one. You can set the Target server using the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new data source on WebLogic with your JNDI name,
Open WebLogic on the localhost using the following steps:

1. Run cmd as Administrator then change directory to 'WebLogic_Home'
2. > cd C:\WebLogicServer
3. > oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd

oracle wizard should be displayed, select the update button and proceed with 'next' until you reach the following screen:
[screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGU1G.png)

Open WebLogic on Localhost, enter your pre-specified username and password

From the left panel Domain_Structure

````
open services -> Data Sources ->

New Generic Data source-> type your JNDI name and data source name -> 

next -> next -> next -> 

fill all your project's database data -> next -> test -> check the checkbox of the default server -> finish```

then re-run your project it should work.
````